# How to check for collisions in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

As you can see in the code there is a trash can and a square that I can move. My goal is to make a game so they have to make the square go to the trash can. But I have no idea how.

Code:

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init
    red = (255,0,0)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    x = 100
    y = 100
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
    pygame.display.set_caption("recycling game!")
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
        keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        if keyPressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            y-=3;
        keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keyPressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y+=3;
        keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x-=3;
        keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x+=3;
        rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,(x,y,50,50))
        imagevariable = pygame.image.load("recycle.png")
        imagevariable = pygame.transform.scale(imagevariable,(100,100))
        screen.blit(imagevariable,(380,380))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Also, I want to make a timer in the top of the pygame screen so please help with collision and timer!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :-). A little tip: sometimes asking too many questions makes it harder to answer any single one of them. Asking a single question keeps the post focused. I recommend [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63094400/edit) your question to focus on collision. Once you get that working, you can open another question for the timer.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. Will do(:. Also can you answer my question about how to make a timer then. Because I really do need help

Answer (score 2):

I will answer to get you started on some simple collision.

Collision in PyGame is mainly done with `pygame.Rect` [rectangles](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).  The code defines a rectangle that goes around edge of the images, and when one rectangle overlaps another, that means they've hit (collided).

A pygame Rect is just a simple `x` and `y` co-ordinate of the top-left corner, along with a `width` and a `height`.  You already have a red square, to make this into a pygame Rect, we just combine the `x,y` and the `50,50`:

```
# Create the moveable item 
x = 100
y = 100
rubbish_rect = pygame.Rect( x, y, 50, 50 )
```

The image for the recycling bit requires a few more steps.  This is because we want the rectangle to be the same size as the image.  Your code loads the image, scales it, and then draws it at `380,380`.  One of the useful properties of pygame Surfaces, that they have a `.get_rect()` member function, which will automatically give you a rectangle that is the same size as the image.  We can then move the rect to `380,380` and use it for image-drawing position:

```
# Create the recycling-bin object
recycling_image = pygame.image.load("recycle.png")                                # Load the image 
recycling_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( recycling_image, ( 100, 100 ) )   # Scale to size
recycling_rect  = recycling_image.get_rect()                                      # Make a Rect for it
recycling_rect.topleft = ( 380, 380 )
```

So now there is a Rect for both the rubbish item, and the recycling bin.  We can use the Rect member [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) `Rect.colliderect( other_rect )`, which will return `True` if the rectangles `Rect` and `other_rect` overlap.

This allows us to check for the item entering the recycling quite simply:

```
if ( rubbish_rect.colliderect( recycling_rect ) ):
    print( "*rubbish has been recycled*" )
```

Obviously this is true even if the rubbish hits the side of the bin, so you really want a "bounce off" when the item does not enter at the top.

I hope this answer gives you a start on object collision.

Reference Code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()                   # <<-- Added '()'

# Create the recycling-bin object
recycling_image = pygame.image.load("recycle.png")                                # Load the image 
recycling_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( recycling_image, ( 100, 100 ) )   # Scale to size
recycling_rect  = recycling_image.get_rect()                                      # Make a Rect for it
recycling_rect.topleft = ( 380, 380 )                                             # Position the Rect

# Create the moveable item 
x = 100
y = 100
rubbish_rect = pygame.Rect( x, y, 50, 50 )

red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("recycling game!")
while True:
    # handle user input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keyPressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        rubbish_rect.y -= 3;
    keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keyPressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        rubbish_rect.y += 3;
    keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        rubbish_rect.x -= 3;
    keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        rubbish_rect.x += 3;

    # Draw the screen
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect( screen, red, rubbish_rect )
    #imagevariable = pygame.image.load("recycle.png")
    #imagevariable = pygame.transform.scale(imagevariable,(100,100))
    #screen.blit(imagevariable,(380,380))
    screen.blit( recycling_image, recycling_rect )

    # Did the rubbish enter the bin?
    if ( rubbish_rect.colliderect( recycling_rect ) ):
        print( "*rubbish has been recycled*" )
        # move the rubbich back to the start
        rubbish_rect.topleft = ( x, y )  # starting x,y

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH I HAVE LITERALLY BEEN WATCHING EVER VIDEO ON YOUTUBE!!! YOU HELPED SO MUCH. ok seriously thanks a lot you saved my life. i made some chnges so that when the ball touched the trash can i quit pygame. and thats about it

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> ```
> screen.blit(imagevariable,(380,380))
> ```

Let's change those [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)):

```
trash_x, trash_y = 380, 380
screen.blit(imagevariable, (trash_x, trash_y))
inc = 3  # the increment that player moves on each keypress
```

Now we're in a good position to assess whether player is near trash:

```
is_near = ((trash_x - inc < x < trash_x + inc)
       and (trash_y - inc < y < trash_y + inc))
```

Armed with that `is_near` boolean, you can decide what should be displayed next.